# How to get user id of order from order entity metadata wrapper

Tags: 7, commerce, entities

I am implementing `hook_commerce_cart_line_item_refresh()`. It will be receiving line item and entity metadata wrapper for the commerce order.

How can I get user id of order from its metadata wrapper without loading user object like this

```
$uid = $order_wrapper->owner->value()->uid
```

With above line it will be loading user object. I would like to avoid loading user object and simply take uid directly.

Following line does not work:

```
$uid = $order_wrapper->uid;
```

Or should I think of loading order object? As it might be already in static cache.

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's the same as any property on a metadata wrapper:

```
$uid = $order_wrapper->uid->value();
```

> Or should I think of loading order object?

You can't have an entity metadata wrapper without an underlying entity, so the object you're referring to is already 'loaded'. You can get it with

```
$order = $order_wrapper->value();
```

Comment: Oh, why didn't I try that simple line!!

Comment: This is not correct, check 3rd answer,
$uid = $order_wrapper->author->uid->value();

Comment: The order entity has a uid property @Ponzio - it's correct. Your method is identical to this, except it involves unnecessary database calls

Answer (score 2):

You need to get `uid` from the entity object.

```
$uid = $order_wrapper->value()->uid;
```

Answer (score 0):

For a multi-valued entity reference field you can get the raw values using this pattern

```
$wrapper->field_multiple->raw()
```

This would return an array like this:

```
array(0 => 123, 1 => 456)
```

Answer (score -1):

Correct answer is:

$uid = $order_wrapper->author->uid->value();

Comment: This isn't right - see [`commerce_order_entity_property_info()`](http://www.rit.edu/drupal/api/drupal/sites!all!modules!commerce!modules!order!commerce_order.info.inc/function/commerce_order_entity_property_info/7.43). The related user entity is available through the `owner` property, not `author`. This code might work for a node, or for a custom property you or something else has defined on commerce_order, but would be equally redundant as using `$order_wrapper->owner->uid->value()`, forcing a load of the user object just to get an ID you already have in `$order_wrapper->uid->value()`